# C++ Vector not changing value after being altered in a method

Tags: c++, vector, nodes

I'm trying to create a class for a node in a directed graph (I don't know much about them so forgive if I've messed up any terms).
Whenever I add a pointer to n2 to n1's outNodes vector, I want a pointer to n1 to be added to n2's inNodes vector. I hope that made sense and here is my code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Node {
private:
  static int nextId;
  int id;
  std::vector<Node*> ptr_outNodes;
  std::vector<Node*> ptr_inNodes;
public:
  Node() {
    id = nextId++;
  }

  int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  void setInNodes(Node n) {
    ptr_inNodes.push_back(&n);
  }
  void setOutNodes(Node n) {
    ptr_outNodes.push_back(&n);
    n.setInNodes(*this);
  }

  std::vector<Node*> getOutNodes() {
    return ptr_outNodes;
  }

  std::vector<Node*> getInNodes() {
    return ptr_inNodes;
  }
};

int Node::nextId = 0;


int main() {
  Node n1;
  Node n2;

  n1.setOutNodes(n2);
  std::cout << n2.getInNodes().size();
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I have it set to return the size of n2's inNodes. When I run the program I see that it's size is 0. If I print out the size within the setInNodes method, I get the result 1 which is odd to me. Also, if I change my main function to this:

```cpp
int main() {
  Node n1;
  Node n2;

  n1.setOutNodes(n2);
  n2.setInNodes(n1);
  std::cout << n2.getInNodes().size();
  return 0;
}
```

I get the result 1. Adding that line shows that the function is working, so I believe something is going wrong when I call setInNodes() from setOutNodes(). I've been staring at this for the past half hour, so if someone could help me that would be great, thanks!

Comment: Both `setInNodes` and `setOutNodes` push the address of the function parameter that is passed by value, so it's a copy of the original, and goes out of scope at the end of the function. This is undefined behavior. Both of your `get*` functions return the vector by value as well, so another copy. That's not necessarily a problem, but you do need to be aware of it in case you try something like `getOutNodes().push_back(whatever)` and wonder why the original vector is unchanged.

Comment: @RetiredNinja So should I try and store references in the vector instead?

Comment: What you should do is fully learn and understand: 1) the differences between passing parameters by value versus by reference, and 2) the differences between objects declared in automatic and dynamic scopes. Both are fundamental, core principles of how objects work in C++ and it is imperative to understand this subject matter completely. A complete discussion of these core topics cannot be fully summarized in just one or two sentences on Stackoverflow, but is the subject of multiple chapters in every C++ textbook, which is where you can look for more information and detailed explanations.

Comment: `void addInNode(Node* node)` as indeed `&n` takes the address of a copied node struct, on the stack, which gives a dangerous dangling pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are providing the methods `setInNodes` and `setOutNodes` with *copies* of the original Node object. The pointer you're pushing into the vector is the address of that *copy*, not of the original object.

To push the address of the original Node object, you need to pass a Node-pointer to the function.

Code:

```cpp
... // Your Node class code

void setInNodes(Node *n) {
  ptr_inNodes.push_back(n);
}
void setOutNodes(Node *n) {
  ptr_outNodes.push_back(n);
  n.setInNodes(this);
}
...

// in the main function:
n1.setOutNodes(&n2);
n2.setInNodes(&n1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code :

```
void setInNodes(Node n) {
    ptr_inNodes.push_back(&n);
  }
  void setOutNodes(Node n) {
    ptr_outNodes.push_back(&n);
    n.setInNodes(*this);
  }
```

You're passing `Node` by value (its a temporary). Then you're adding the pointer to the temporary to you're vector. When you're function (`setxxx`) goes out of scope, the temporary is destroyed, and hence the stored pointer is a pointer to an invalid object. Accessing/dereferencing the pointer after the function exits is undefined behavior (ie the program can do anything).

As mentioned elsewhere you can either pass in a pointer or a reference.

```
void setXxNode(Node& node)...
```

Passing by reference would be my choice, as it requires a value (shows intent). One then adds the address of the reference to the vector, but note that the lifetime of object referred to must exceed that of the object that now holds the pointer.